# Matching by and for non-unique ID's

Tags: r

I have a some large network analysis data which looks like this ("friendship"=friendship score student gave to alter):

```
studentid  alterid   friendship
 30401001 30401002  1.308245549
 30401001 30401003 -0.671986154
 30401001 30401004  0.039891905
 30401002 30401001  0.669867969
 30401002 30401003  0.967399033
 30401002 30401004 -0.902678435
 30401003 30401001  0.002150519
 30401003 30401002 -0.272702372
 30401003 30401004 -0.441293873
 30401004 30401001 -0.902678435
 30401004 30401002 -0.902678435
 30401004 30401003 -0.902678435
```

I want to create an "alter_friendship" variable which is the friendship score that the alter gave to the student. The result should look like this:

```
 studentid  alterid  friendship  alter_friendship   
 30401001 30401002  1.308245549  0.669867969
 30401001 30401003 -0.671986154  0.002150519
 30401001 30401004  0.039891905 -0.902678435
 30401002 30401001  0.669867969  1.308245549 
 30401002 30401003  0.967399033 -0.272702372
 30401002 30401004 -0.902678435 -0.902678435
 30401003 30401001  0.002150519  0.039891905
 30401003 30401002 -0.272702372  0.967399033
 30401003 30401004 -0.441293873 -0.902678435
 30401004 30401001 -0.902678435  0.039891905
 30401004 30401002 -0.902678435 -0.902678435
 30401004 30401003 -0.902678435 -0.441293873
```

I tried using match combined with adply:

```
net$alter_friendship<-adply(.margins=1,net$friendship[match(net$alterid,net$studentid)])
```

This does gives correct answers only for student number 1 (30401001) but wrong answers for all the rest.

If anybody has better ideas it would be great.

Comment: It seems that, in this case, you could just do `DF$friendship[order(DF$alterid, DF$studentid)]` although I'm not sure how error-prone that is.

Answer (score 4):

`merge(d,d,by.x=c('studentid','alterid'),by.y=c('alterid','studentid'))`

will produce:

```
   studentid  alterid friendship.x friendship.y
1   30401001 30401002  1.308245549  0.669867969
2   30401001 30401003 -0.671986154  0.002150519
3   30401001 30401004  0.039891905 -0.902678435
4   30401002 30401001  0.669867969  1.308245549
5   30401002 30401003  0.967399033 -0.272702372
6   30401002 30401004 -0.902678435 -0.902678435
7   30401003 30401001  0.002150519 -0.671986154
8   30401003 30401002 -0.272702372  0.967399033
9   30401003 30401004 -0.441293873 -0.902678435
10  30401004 30401001 -0.902678435  0.039891905
11  30401004 30401002 -0.902678435 -0.902678435
12  30401004 30401003 -0.902678435 -0.441293873
```

where d is your input data set:

```
d <- structure(list(studentid = c(30401001L, 30401001L, 30401001L, 
30401002L, 30401002L, 30401002L, 30401003L, 30401003L, 30401003L, 
30401004L, 30401004L, 30401004L), alterid = c(30401002L, 30401003L, 
30401004L, 30401001L, 30401003L, 30401004L, 30401001L, 30401002L, 
30401004L, 30401001L, 30401002L, 30401003L), friendship = c(1.308245549, 
-0.671986154, 0.039891905, 0.669867969, 0.967399033, -0.902678435, 
0.002150519, -0.272702372, -0.441293873, -0.902678435, -0.902678435, 
-0.902678435)), .Names = c("studentid", "alterid", "friendship"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `sapply` for example:

```
df$alter_friendship <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) {
  with(df, friendship[studentid == alterid[i] & alterid == studentid[i]])
})
```

Result:

```
df
#   studentid  alterid   friendship alter_friendship
#1   30401001 30401002  1.308245549      0.669867969
#2   30401001 30401003 -0.671986154      0.002150519
#3   30401001 30401004  0.039891905     -0.902678435
#4   30401002 30401001  0.669867969      1.308245549
#5   30401002 30401003  0.967399033     -0.272702372
#6   30401002 30401004 -0.902678435     -0.902678435
#7   30401003 30401001  0.002150519     -0.671986154
#8   30401003 30401002 -0.272702372      0.967399033
#9   30401003 30401004 -0.441293873     -0.902678435
#10  30401004 30401001 -0.902678435      0.039891905
#11  30401004 30401002 -0.902678435     -0.902678435
#12  30401004 30401003 -0.902678435     -0.441293873
```

Comment: Great answer easy to understand and to implement. Thanks docendo discimus

Answer (score 2):

[dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr)  can do this via a self-join (using Marat's data):

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(d, d, by = c("studentid" = "alterid", "alterid" = "studentid"))
```

But why does the code in your question fail?  The code was (changing `net` to `d` for clarity):

```
adply(.margins=1, d$friendship[match(d$alterid, d$studentid)])
```

R interprets the second (unnamed) argument as the `.data` argument.  Consequently, `adply` doesn't actually do anything except number the rows, because it hasn't been given a function to perform, and the default function is NULL.

All the code does, then, is use the result of `match` to index the data frame.  When there are multiple matches, as in your case, `match` returns the first matching row.  Hence the unexpected result.

```
> cbind(d[, -3], match = match(d$alterid, d$studentid))
   studentid  alterid match
1   30401001 30401002     4
2   30401001 30401003     7
3   30401001 30401004    10
4   30401002 30401001     1
5   30401002 30401003     7
6   30401002 30401004    10
7   30401003 30401001     1
8   30401003 30401002     4
9   30401003 30401004    10
10  30401004 30401001     1
11  30401004 30401002     4
12  30401004 30401003     7
```

I suspect you intended `adply` to iterate through each row, finding the exact match on both the criteria `studentid == alterid & alterid == studentid`, like this:

```
cbind(d, V1 = adply(d, 1, function(x) {
  d[d$alterid == x$studentid & d$studentid == x$alterid, "friendship"]
  })$V1)
```

That is pretty inefficient, though, compared with the other answers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation nacnudus. Your suspicion is correct. I really need to work on my function writing skills, and your explanation makes it much easier.